# transpose DataFrame to another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I need help to create DataFrame like below

| City | Date | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Moscow | 03.04.2022 | 1 |
| Moscow | 02.04.2022 | 4 |
| Moscow | 01.04.2022 | 7 |
| Barcelona | 03.04.2022 | 2 |
| Barcelona | 02.04.2022 | 5 |

...

from this DataFrame

| City | 03.04.2022 | 02.04.2022 | 01.04.2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moscow | 1 | 4 | 7 |
| Barcelona | 2 | 5 | 8 |
| Paris | 3 | 6 | 9 |

If you know the link to solve my question, I will be grateful

Answer (score 2):

You can use `melt`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='City', var_name='Date',value_name='count').sort_values(by='City')
```

sorting is optional

output:

```
>>>
        City        Date  count
1  Barcelona  03.04.2022      2
4  Barcelona  02.04.2022      5
7  Barcelona  01.04.2022      8
0     Moscow  03.04.2022      1
3     Moscow  02.04.2022      4
6     Moscow  01.04.2022      7
2      Paris  03.04.2022      3
5      Paris  02.04.2022      6
8      Paris  01.04.2022      9
```